# Whitelist requests from certain routes

Tags: ember.js

Whenever a user is not authenticated they are transitioned to the login route/view. I am needing a way for a user to be able to get to a few routes when they aren't authenticated like 'password-reset', 'new-password', etc. Is there a way to whitelist the requested route and if it's not one of those routes transition to the login route? Thanks in advance for the help.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    store = @controllerFor('application').get('store')
    if !$.cookie('apiKey')
      @transitionTo 'login'
      return store.createRecord('session')
    store.find('session', 'current').then (session)->
      session
    , (error)=>
      if error.status == 403
        @transitionTo 'login'
        return store.createRecord('session')
      else
        throw error
```

Comment: Personally I'd move the authenticated routes somewhere deeper than application route. and have an unauthenticated region

Comment: Could you just show a general idea of what you mean? I'm newish to ember. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('auth', function(){
    this.resource('colors', {path:'/colors'}, function(){
      this.resource('color', {path: '/:id'});
    });
  });
  this.resource('unauth', function(){
    this.resource('dogs', {path:'/dogs'}, function(){
      this.resource('cats', {path: '/:id'});
    });
  });
});

App.AuthRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    store = @controllerFor('application').get('store')
    if !$.cookie('apiKey')
      @transitionTo 'login'
      return store.createRecord('session')
    store.find('session', 'current').then (session)->
      session
    , (error)=>
      if error.status == 403
        @transitionTo 'login'
        return store.createRecord('session')
      else
        throw error
   }
});
```

Comment: Nope, not if you don't need to return a particular model from it.

Comment: So I've been trying to implement your solution and one thing I wondered about is if I will have to use the top level resource in all the link-to's and whatnot. So do I have to do unauth.login and such for every route or is there a way to remove the need for that?

Comment: only if they are route's on that resource, if they are resources you can just say `{{link-to 'login'}}`

Comment: Would it be odd to name them all as resources even though they technically aren't?

Comment: I'm going to assume they were just routes right in the root of your router, so they were implicitly `application.login`.  You can still put them there and they would be in the unauth, everything that isn't under the auth resource would be considered unauth.  Really it's up to you, I like be super verbose, and if you wanted them to live under unauth, and not say unauth.login then you'd have to make them resources.  Nobody would judge you.